# When accessing site from external network using IE JS/CSS(YUI) based UI is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, yui

We have ASP.NET application in which we have used the YUI to generated the popup for user interface. Now when I amd testing the locally isntalled site the popups are comming correctctly withoug any error and also getting displayed correctly on all the browwsers (including IE 7/8/9).

However when the site is exposed on the server and i tried to test it from the outside network the YUI popup's are not getting genrated correclty like if some Javascript or CSS are not getting loaded or are cached. Generally Ctr+F5 does the trick to flush local cache and to fix the issue we have added query parameters xyz.css?v=10 trick. But its not working. Now this issue is showing only on the IE(6/7/8/9) and other browsers are working correctly. To check the issue i again logged into the production box and found that popup is appearing correctly on IE also.

Now i am not having  clue how it could possibly happen. Does any one has came across anything like this? What could be the cause of the issue and how to fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: did you try to put some timestamp instead of "10" in the "xyz.css?v=10 trick" ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, IE caches GET responses.
The xyz.css?v=10 trick is used when you want it to use cached CSS but only as long as it is the same version. Whenever you change something in the css you need to change the url (ie xyz.css?v=20).
If you want IE to NEVER use the cached css, you need the URL to look different everytime. you can do that by adding some timestamp to the url.
something like:

```
xyz.css?v=201201180600123
```

(201201180600123 is a timestamp)